# Compiling Data into .json file

Tags: php, html, json

I need to compile multiple data from my Server in a single .json file.

What i mean:

Here are the values stored:

```
https://www.design-24.eu/listener/1/catch.php
https://www.design-24.eu/listener/2/catch.php
...and so on.
```

Now i need to compile then into this format:

```
{"all":*all together*, "channels":{"1":*value1*,"2":*value2*,"3":*value3*,"4":*value4*,"5":*value5*,"6":*value6*}}
```

Help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking? Compile what data? Where are you getting the values from and what format are they in? etc

Comment: The Values are just number output from the server. And i need them to get put in this .json file like showed.

Comment: Do you have a list of all sites and are they all your sites?

Comment: Yes these are my Sites.

https://www.design-24.eu/listener/1/catch.php
https://www.design-24.eu/listener/2/catch.php
https://www.design-24.eu/listener/3/catch.php
https://www.design-24.eu/listener/4/catch.php
https://www.design-24.eu/listener/5/catch.php
https://www.design-24.eu/listener/6/catch.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
$urls = array();
$urls[] = 'https://www.design-24.eu/listener/1/catch.php';
$urls[] = 'https://www.design-24.eu/listener/2/catch.php';
$urls[] = 'https://www.design-24.eu/listener/3/catch.php';
// add as many of the above as you want

$x = count( $urls );
$arr = array();
$arr[ 'all' ] = 0;
$arr[ 'channels' ] = array();

for ( $z = 0; $z < $x; $z++ ) {
  $json = file_get_contents( $urls[ $z ] );
  $json = preg_replace( "/[^0-9]/", "", $json );
  $arr[ 'all' ] = $arr[ 'all' ] + $json;
  $arr[ 'channels' ][ ( $z + 1 ) ] = $json;
}

$output = json_encode( $arr );

$f = fopen( "result.json", "w" ); // change result.json to the filename you want to write to
fwrite( $f, $output );
fclose( $f );
```

Comment: I get this as an Output:
{"all":"\ufeff0\ufeff1\ufeff0\ufeff1\ufeff1\ufeff0","channels":{"1":"\ufeff0","2":"\ufeff1","3":"\ufeff0","4":"\ufeff1","5":"\ufeff1","6":"\ufeff0"}}

Comment: @NLXY Correct. That is the json-encoded output of the urls you provided.

Comment: Oh ok it works! But it added the numbers like this: 1 + 2 + 2 = 122 not 1 + 2 + 2 = 5

Comment: @NLXY I hadn't realized that was what you wanted. I've updated the answer. It should work the way to want now.

Comment: Now its just outputing 0 in the "all" array

Comment: {"all":0,"channels":{"1":"\ufeff1","2":"\ufeff0","3":"\ufeff0","4":"\ufeff0","5":"\ufeff0","6":"\ufeff0"}}

Comment: @NLXY I've updated by answer to strip non-numeric characters using "$json = preg_replace( "/[^0-9]/", "", $json );". This will solve the immediate problem, although it's not ideal. The problem is caused because your catch.php script needs to include "header('Content-Type:text/plain');" before echo'ing its output. If you make that change, you likely won't need "$json = preg_replace( "/[^0-9]/", "", $json );".

Comment: @NLXY Great! I've fixed my comment immediately above to say "header('Content-Type:text/plain');" instead of "header('Content-Type:text/html');" in case you decide to make that fix.

Comment: Can you fix my code from catch.php if i post it here?

Comment: @NLXY To comply with Stackoverflow rules, post it as a new question and then post the link here.

Comment: i can't Ask a new Question... Im limited

Comment: @NLXY Ok. Post your code to https://pastebin.com/ and post the link here.

Comment: I've added the header function above the echo $txt. You can see the result at https://pastebin.com/kdz1nz6a